# struct and array problem in C

Tags: c

Here is the problem:
I have a struct like this:

```
struct{
    Variable a;
    Variable 2;
    char ch[1];
}
```

I need to point `ch` to another `struct` containing several `char` arrays.  No, I CAN NOT change the first struct definition at all.  I just need some how to put the first byte of my second `struct` in `ch[1]` and I simply don't know how to do this. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get this from? This isn't even C. So you *must* change that.

Comment: I guess this is an assignment? Please would you be careful enough to present us the real question that was posed to you? What did you try? Is it by any chance that you are supposed to extend the `struct` by a longer character array?

Comment: This is C in at least pseudo-code form. the struct should have a name and be terminated with a semi-colon but we know what he means.

Comment: @CashCow, I don't know what you mean by "C in at least pseudo-code form". Either it is C or pseudo-code. For me such a sloppy writing just shows that we didn't even see the real question, yet.

Answer (score 5):

You can't "point" an array at something else because an array is not a pointer. An array of one `char` is just an array in which you can store a single `char` value.

If you can't change the definition from an array to a pointer then you can't make it "point". I'm afraid it's as simple as that.

Comment: No it is not as simple as that. This is C, not C++. You allocate with malloc and can allocate more than you think... This is a very common C paradigm.

Comment: @CashCow: In C99 you _can_ have a FAM as the last member of a struct but it still isn't a pointer and you can't make such a member point at a different area of memory. I'm not sure whether this is what you are referring to?

Comment: @CashCow, @Charles is entirely correct. As presented by the OP the question makes no sense at all in C. That's it. In your answer you try to interpret the question in basically trying to guess what an instructor might have asked at the beginning. But this is just guess work. *The* correct answer to the question as it is posed is this one here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common paradigm in C. The last char is just a placeholder for variable data, and in reality you will allocate a larger buffer and overrun the 1 character. This is perfectly legal.

You cannot change the struct but when you call `malloc()` to allocate it you allocate some extra bytes.

What you need in place of the `char[1]` is a pointer (to the other struct).

Let us give your struct a name:

```
typedef struct{
    Variable a;
    Variable 2;
    char ch[1];
} Element;
```

in your code:

```
Element * elt = malloc( sizeof( Element ) + sizeof( CharArrayStruct* ) - 1);
 /* fill your struct */
*(CharArrayStruct **)elt.ch = &myCharArrayStruct;
/* later on reading it back */
CharArrayStruct * pcas = *(CharArrayStruct **)elt.ch;
```

Note `elt.ch` is the address of the start of an array, not a char. Note that its contents are an `OtherStruct*` therefore it must be cast to `CharArrayStruct**`

Comment: I had the same guess. This sort of thing even has a name in the standard. It is called flexible array member, and should have empty `[]` for `ch`. But your allocation code is completely bogus: first, don't cast return of `malloc`, beginners often are struck by the missing prototype error. Then your parenthesis don't match and your dangling `-1` is just obscure.

Comment: Thanks CashCow for your answer. Jens answers as a "compiler" :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could come up with a third `struct`:

```
struct c {
    struct a *a;
    struct b *b;
    struct c *next;
}
```

Append a new one of these to a head each time you want to store an association from your `struct a` to your `struct b` -- when you need to look one up, walk down the linked list, doing pointer comparisons on `.a` until you find the matching one, and return the `.b`.

Don't forget to *remove* these entries from the linked list when you `free()` `struct a` objects, and don't forget to `NULL` the `.b` members when you `free()` `struct b` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do in a safe way, at least not unless you're in some low-memory environment. A single char (which is what your `ch` field is) only consists of 1 byte; this is simply not enough bits to point to any memory location in your virtual memory space. Even if you cast that `char` to `(void *)` you won't be able to address the vast, vast majority of your memory with it.

Perhaps you should step back and tell us what you're *actually* trying to accomplish, rather than what you think you need to do in order to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what you literally say in the actual question body ("I just need some how to put the first byte of my second struct in `ch[1]` and I simply don't know how to do this."), and I disregard the first sentence that talks about "pointing", you could do it like this:

```
struct{
    Variable a;
    Variable 2;
    char ch[1];
} my_struct_that_cant_be_changed;

struct my_other_struct x;

my_struct_that_cant_be_changed.ch[0] = *(char *) &x;
```

This simply reads the first `char` from the other struct (in the variable `x`) and assigns that value into the 1-character array of the first struct.

Note that this seems completely pointless to me, but it does (sort of) what you want.

Comment: Close but wrong, you can't assign a char to just some random first byte of another struct.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not clear what you want to do. It's not possible to "point" to another struct using a one-byte value. Secondly, it doesn't make sense to place the first byte of the second struct in ch[0] without doing anything else.

The way the struct is constructed I suspect that that it is designed to be a *variable length struct*. (Other answers have touched this, but they use the extra space to store a pointer, not the entire string.)

By allocating some extra bytes, you would get the following layout in memory:

```
+----
| Variable a
| Variable 2 (sic)
| ch[0]
+------ Extra memory below:
| ch[1]
| ...
| ch[N]
+------
```

You can allocate this by:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(Element) + N);
```

You can access the element like `p->ch[4]` and access `ch` as a string using `p->ch`.

Now, it's up to you to fill your `ch` array with the string (or whatever) you want.